# Change background image of sharethis Facebook counter with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, sharethis

```html
<span class="stMainServices st-facebook-counter" style="background-image: url(http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_counter.png);">
    &nbsp;
    <img src="http://w.sharethis.com/images/check-big.png" style="position: absolute; top: -7px; right: -7px; width: 19px; height: 19px; max-width: 19px; max-height: 19px; display: none;">
</span>
```

I cannot change background-image (facebook_counter) with my own image.
I tried to change it by using
`.css("background-image","url...")` and `.attr("style","new style")` but maybe I am using the selector part wrong.

Also I am getting this code by using wp socializer in wordpress installation.

Comment: what selector are you using?

Comment: Seems to be working here .. `.css()` should work  http://jsfiddle.net/GadTt/

Answer (score 0):

This is because of CSS precedence. Inline styles (using the `style="blah"` declarations in tags) have a higher precedence than items in your stylesheet.

You can override it with the `!important` flag on your style, but [this is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css).

```
.st-facebook-counter
{
    background-image: url('someotherimage.jpg') !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so .. using `.css()` directly manipulates the inline style tag  ... So the image should change.

Comment: Not exactly. If you inspect the element, in your jsfiddle, it doesn't have the css in your javascript applied. If you add in the css window:
`.stMainServices { ​background-image: none !important; }` the CSS wins even over the jQuery. ​

Comment: Besides, why do in JS what you can easily handle in CSS?

Comment: That is because of `!important` has it has highest precedence.. Try removing and see what happens  ..

Comment: It's a bad practice to use `!important` .. that has to be the last resort if nothing else works

Comment: You can see the fiddle here that uses classes instead http://jsfiddle.net/GadTt/1/

Comment: I agree, it's bad practice. What the OP is attempting to modify however is brought in via JS (its the ShareThis 3rd party social integration). That makes additional JS more painful to work with where as the CSS would just work. I looks like ShareThis has a different approach however: http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475031-customizing-facebook-like-google-1

Answer (score 0):

To change the background image for example facebook:

By default sharethis works like this:

```
<span class="st_facebook"></span>
```

We need to change above to

```
<span class="st_facebook_custom"></span>
```

Then add the styling to the class:

```
        .st_facebook_custom{
    background: url("http://path/to/image/file") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    padding:0px 16px 0 0;
}
```

It should work perfectly with your image you require.